# Vaadin Restart Problem with Struts

Tags: vaadin

I want to restart the vaadin application whenever I got a hit to the controller.

```
<action path="/vaadinController"
      type="com.thomson.steam.steamadmin.action.VaadinController"
      scope="request">
      <forward name="createuser" path="/VaadinApplication/?restartApplication" />       
</action>
```

I am passing `?restartApplication` to my VaadinApplication but it does not work through struts.
If I execute by directly hitting the url `/VaadinApplication/?restartApplication` it works fine and the application is getting restarted.

Can anyone help me out to solve this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem is resolved. Instead passing the variable in the struts-config.xml file I passed the parameter while invoking the action class itself.It works fine now.

```
/vaadinController?restartApplication
```